# Viewing the code generated by @synthesize for getter/setter

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, code-generation

Is it possible to view the exact code generated by @synthesize?

Comment: Soitanly. I though I could learn something from viewing that code.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/589348/412916 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/917884/ http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/10/memory-and-thread-safe-custom-property.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can read the Clang compiler source to see the C++ code that generates the getter and setter methods:

http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/lib/CodeGen/CGObjC.cpp

It's pretty cryptic but that's the most accurate way of seeing the code generated.

You can also look at the objc_getProperty and objc_setProperty implementations in [Apple's runtime implementation](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-371.2/runtime/Accessors.subproj/objc-accessors.m). While not literally the same as the code that is generated, this code is much easier to read and gives a clear indication of what a proper getter and setter should do.

Comment: If "clear" includes having lots of dead code in your file, then yeah. But you're right, the good stuff is buried in there as well.

Answer (score 5):

Sure it is.  Go to the .m file where you've `@synthesized` the property, then from the Build menu, choose "Show Assembly Code".  The compiler conveniently puts in stuff like:

```
    .align  4, 0x90
"-[Foo setStr:]":
Leh_func_begin2:
Lfunc_begin2:
....
```

And

```
    .align  4, 0x90
"-[Foo answer]":
Leh_func_begin3:
Lfunc_begin3:
....
```

Oh, you wanted *Objective-C* code?  Sorry, this is done by the compiler, and the compiler *reads* Objective-C, but *writes* in Assembly.