# Which ways are correct to use when using @synthesize

Tags: iphone, ios4

I'm a bit confused when it comes to synthesize properties.

Lets say that I have this property in my *.h file.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *aString;
```

And in my *.m file I synthesize it.
    @synthesize aString;

I know that the compiler will generate setters and getters when Im using synthesize. But how does these setters and getters look like?

And when I shall give aString a value, which ways are correct?

```
self.aString = @"My New String"; // This will use the setter?
aString = @"My new String"; //This will not use the setter and retain the string, right?
aString = [@"My new string" retain]; //This will not use the setter, but it will retain the string ?
[self setAString:@"My new string"]; //This will also use the setter?
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: self.aString = @"My New String"; and [self setAString:@"My new string"]; will use the seter !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *aString;
```

...followed by:

```
@synthesize aString;
```

...your class gets three basic things:

1. An instance-variable called `aString` that you can reference directly within your class.
2. A getter function with a signature `- (NSString*) aString;` that returns the instance variable.
3. A setter function with a signature `- (void) setAString: (NSString*) value;` that retains the parameter that is passed in and assigns it to the instance variable (and releases any previously retained value, if one exists);

Implementation-wise, these generated methods and fields might look like:

```
//in the .h file
@interface MyClass {
    NSString* aString;
}

- (NSString*) aString;
- (void) setAString: (NSString*) value;

@end


//in the .m file
@implementation MyClass

- (NSString*) aString {
    return aString;
}

- (void) setAString: (NSString*) value {
    if (aString != value) {
        [aString release];
        aString = [value retain];
    }
}

@end
```

So to answer the rest of your questions:

```
self.aString = @"My New String"; // This will use the setter?  Yes, and it will retain the string.
aString = @"My new String"; //This will not use the setter and retain the string, right?  Right.
aString = [@"My new string" retain]; //This will not use the setter, but it will retain the string?  Right again.
[self setAString:@"My new string"]; //This will also use the setter?  Yep.
```

As for which are correct, they all are, depending upon what you want and assuming that you understand how the behavior differs between using each one, particularly with respect to releasing/retaining property values.  For instance, this code will leak memory:

```
self.aString = @"Value 1";  //go through the setter, which retains the string
aString = @"Value 2";        //bypass the setter, the 'Value 1' string will not be released
```

...and this equivalent code will not:

```
self.aString = @"Value 1";  //go through the setter, which retains the string
self.aString = @"Value 2";  //go through the setter again to release the first string
```

Comment: Very good answer, learned some new things about obj-c programming that might fix some of my bugs!

Comment: That setter should check that `aString != value` or the retain count could accidentally drop to 0.
`if (aString != value) {
    [aString release];
    aString = [value retain];
}`

Comment: Thanks! That was pretty much what I though. But it's nice to get it confirmed:)

Answer (score 2):

The getter and setter are used when you use "dot" syntax (e.g. `self.aString`, `self.aString = ...`) or message syntax (e.g. `[self aString]`, `[self setAString:...]`).

Assigning directly to the backing variable (in your case somewhat confusingly named `aString`) will not use the synthesized methods. To change the name of your backing variable, declare it in your interface as a private variable (in the .h):

```
NSString *aString_;
```

and then synthesize it like this:

```
@synthesize aString = aString_;
```

This will use `aString_` as the backing variable for your property, so you can directly reference the storage for your property by using `aString_`.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding what the code would look like, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925725/viewing-the-code-generated-by-synthesize-for-getter-setter).

Regarding which of those lines use the getters/setters: only the 1st and 4th do.

```
self.aString = @"My New String";
[self setAString:@"My new string"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Following are correct setter.

```
self.aString = @"My New String";
[self setAString:@"My new string"];
```